Why can't i shut down entirely despite being able to restart?
I am running ubuntu 20.04 LTS and i am having a strange problem that also affected me when using the latest 24.04 version, when i click to shut down, it works until the monitor's screen goes black, but the led on my pc is still on and the fan is still running, the problem is that it would probably keep on forever since i had tried to wait more than 10 minutes and it was still running, forcing me to power off holding the power button every time, the strangest thing of all is that i can perfectly restart, i think that it might not be a OS problem but a hardware one, but i am unsure, i used the journalctl to try to check but didn't see anything wrong, considering my limited knowledge of looking at logs, log at: https://pastebin.com/M9SpX8zV
Update 1: I checked the log and the only service who got a "timed out" was the bluetooth service so i disabled it, i will try to see if it turns off completely in more then 35 minutes when i finish using it today
Update 2: yesterday when i powered it off, it did properly and the only thing i did was to disable the bluetooth service, i don't know if that was really the problem but i will know if it goes alright today too
Update 3: it worked once more, to think a service like that which doesn't have any use for me could be the root of the problems and that the ubuntu would stop sending image even before it finished stopping the other services
Update 4: Forget what i said, i tried to shut down today just to test it but it happened again, i am sure i waited almost 40 minutes and had to force shut down it again, i looked through the journalctl of that shutdown and didn't find any time/timed out this time, what is happening?

If your shutdown hangs, wait 35 (or more) minutes. Some processes have a 30 minute timeout. In a terminal window, the command sudo journalctl -b -1 -e will show you the end of the previous boot's logs. Check for "timeout" messages.

I am facing the same problem, while I recently installed Ubuntu LTS 24.04. I waited for the shutdown to get done but it took hours and I manually shut it down.
